# Multiple layers of zones on a page google tv jquery ui lib

Tags: google-tv

I'm using google tv jquery ui library to build app. I want to build multi page in one html file. I follow example : http://gtv-resources.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/templates/html-01/index.html, but it using 2 html files to switch between app. Please show me example code to manage multi page in one html file, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do multi page web using single html, you could use layers. You should look at examples BuildPhotoPages or BuildVideoPages here:

https://developers.google.com/tv/web/lib/jquery/

Thanks.

Comment: I looked this example but it very complex, I don't know how to set active/inactive layer. Can you write for me a simple example like that : Page 1 has a slide show, when press enter, switch to page 2 is detail of item selected, when press backspace, slide show in page 1 still focus to selected item, thanks